# Element's onClickOff() event fires early

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I'm pretty sure this isn't a duplicate as I can't find the issue elsewhere or am unable to describe it.

I have this little function `onClickOff()` which temporarily creates an event that runs a bit of code when you click outside of the defined element. This works fine, the issue is that when you click on the button to run the function, it's also registering the click outside of the other element which I don't want.

Try clicking the button in the snippet to see what I mean - I'd like the message not to come up when you click the button but when you click outside of the red div AFTER clicking the button.

**Addition**: I don't want to use `event.stopPropagation();` as this changes functionality within the elements I'm using.

```css
div.click1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClickOff(selector, func) {
        $(document).unbind('click.onOffClick touchstart.onOffClick').bind('click.onOffClick touchstart.onOffClick', function(e) {

            if($(e.target).closest(selector).length === 0) {
                func();
                $(document).unbind('click.onOffClick touchstart.onOffClick');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="click1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
<button type="button" class="click1">Click 1</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click', 'button.click1', function(){
        onClickOff('div.click1', function(){
            alert('You clicked off the square!');
        })
    });
</script>
```

If it helps, this function is mostly used for dropdown menus but I want it to be nice and modular like it is now without changing this bit.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the event propagation once the button is clicked:

```css
div.click1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClickOff(selector, event, func) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(document).unbind('click.onOffClick touchstart.onOffClick').bind('click.onOffClick touchstart.onOffClick', function(e) {

            if($(e.target).closest(selector).length === 0) {
                func();
                $(document).unbind('click.onOffClick touchstart.onOffClick');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="click1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
<button type="button" class="click1">Click 1</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click', 'button.click1', function(e){
        //e.stopPropagation();
        onClickOff('div.click1', e, function(){
            alert('You clicked off the square!');
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way I could implement this within the `onClickOff()` function?

Comment: Well you could pass the event through to the function and cancel it inside...I'll edit it in as an alternative.

Comment: I'll use this for now and if nothing else comes through I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Is using a variable to count the amount of times the function has already been executed an option? you could for example make a variable called count and make the value of count equal to 0 when you click the button to run the function. then in your other function you just add 1 to the value of count and then an if statement to check if the value of count is above 1. If it is then run the code. There might be a cleaner way to accomplish this but this could solve your problem.